# window error: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '.prank/*.* is shown

Tags: python

My PrankHeader.py

```
import os

def removeNumber(str):
    no_digit = []

    for char in str:
        if not char.isdigit():
            no_digit.append(char)

    return no_digit


def renameFiles():
    saved_file = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir("./prank")

    # 1. loop through files in the directory
    for files in os.listdir("./prank"):
        # 2. if the file has the number, delete.
        newFile = removeNumber(files)
        # 3. make the list of char to string
        newFile = ''.join(newFile)
        os.rename(files, newFile)

    os.chdir(saved_file)
```

And my Prank.py

```
import PrankHeader
PrankHeader.renameFiles()
```

Both files are in the folder C:/Users/Myname/Desktop/LocalServer/Prank, and the filder has the folder, Prank, which contains the pictures.

When I tried to implement the program it showed me 
"window error: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '.prank/*.*'

Is there anyone who knows why I have an error?

Comment: you do a os.chdir("Prankt) to directory Prank,. And then in that directory you do a os.listdir("./Prank"), but there is no directory Prank in the directory Prank. Just do a listdir(".") then it should work.

Comment: Actually, there is a Prank directory in the directory Prank. The first Prank is the folder for the program (with dirs and py) and the second Prank is the folder containing bunch of pictures I want to change their names.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the following line

```
for files in os.listdir("./prank"):
```

To

```
for files in os.listdir("."):
```

it should work.  You are running the program from the directory Prank. Then you do a

```
os.chdir("./prank")
```

So you enter the directory Prank/Prank. In that directory you do a

```
os.listdir("./prank"):
```

so it's looking for the directory Prank/prank/prank which it won't find. But with `os.listdir("."):` you are listing files in current directory (which is Prank/Prank)